# Enabling minimize option in JOptionPane.showOptionDialog

Tags: java, swing, awt, joptionpane

Is it possible to enable a minimize option in `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` If yes, how do we set it ?

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane` uses JDialog in order to be displayed. Unfortunately JDialogs cannot have minimize/maximize button.

Comment: Ok so is there no built in dialog in Java swing which would give me a minimize button ? Will I have to make my own custom dialog ?